# Set Struts 2 Variable in JSP to Substring

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a JSP which always gets the Struts property `message`, defined in the Action class,

```
public String getMessage() {
    return "...";
}
```

In the JSP I need to trim the message which has the format `message|E` or `message|M`. I need to remove the trailing pipe and code, and then set it into a variable. The result should be a var.

I tried these and they don't work:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

1) with the $ symbol

```
<s:set name="messageWithoutType" value="${fn:substring(message,0,message.indexOf('|')}" />
```

2) with the # symbol

```
<s:set name="messageWithoutType" value="#{fn:substring(message,0,message.indexOf('|')}" />
```

There is no problem with the original `message`, I can print it without problems. The trims don't work when outputing:

`<p>${messageWithoutType}</p>` => Blank.

`<p><s:property value="#{messageWithoutType}" /></p>` => Blank.

Comment: ognl can also access those methods.  You can do something like message.substring(0, message.indexOf('|')) right in the value without using jstl.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it...

```
<s:set var="messageWithoutType">${fn:substring(message,0,fn:indexOf(message, "|"))}</s:set>
```

then output as

```
<s:property value="decodedUserMessageWithoutType" />
```

In other words, both `substring` and `indexOf` had to be JSTL `fn:` functions.